# AppleScript (+ Alfred workflow) to launch System Settings in Ventura

Tags: macos, applescript, system-preferences

I wanted to create an AppleScript to navigate to the 'Login Items' preference pane in System Settings but all the answers that I can find result in AppleScript errors because the pane ids have changed in newer versions of Mac OS.

I did find the following pane IDs using [this script.](https://www.macscripter.net/t/other-way-to-open-system-preference-pane/72502/6)

```
applescript
tell application "System Settings"
    tell every pane
        its id
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code worked:

```
tell application "System Settings"
    activate
    set the current pane to pane id "com.apple.LoginItems-Settings.extension"
end tell
```

I put all the pane IDs together into Alfred App workflow that can open each pane. You can find it here:
https://github.com/joshuawagner/alfred-system-settings